# Social Login with OpenID Connect - How to validate on the rest api?

Tags: single-page-application, openid-connect

My current setup is the following:

- Single Page Application with Vue
- Rest Backend

The SPA has social login functionality. It uses the authorization code flow with PKCE to retrieve:

- Access Token / Refresh Token
- ID-Token

As it is an SPA, the information is stored in local storage and therefore not 100% secure.

But how do I use this information to actually authenticate against my rest backend? The rest backend actually contains the user data I need after all.

Originally, I thought I could just send my access token or id token to my backend and the backend uses this as proof that I'm the correct user.

Main problems I see:

- Make sure the access token / id token is actually from my application (the SPA)
- Be protected if the tokens are stolen / Minimize the impact of this

For the first problem, the `client_id` might help, which is embedded in the id-token. It is kind of public information (because it is an SPA) and there is no `client_secret`. But the `redirect_uri` is specific to my SPA. Is this enough protection?

If it is my backend could have a list of allowed client ids and providers and check if the client id of the token is one of them.

The second problem is the lifetime of the token. Access tokens are only valid for a short time period and refresh token should be rotated. So it's kind of okay to store these in local storage. But the `id_token` is valid for a longer time. What do to about this?

Is this in general the right track? Or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations RFC 6819 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6819#section-5.1.6) might help.